Is there a name for this type of structured data, and what is a more efficient way to use it?
I'll try to make this question simple so that hopefully the concept is applicable to other fields.
I work with seismic datasets, where N earthquakes are recorded by M seismic stations. There is earthquake-specific information (earthquake ID, magnitude, etc.), and station-specific information (station ID, instrument sampling rate, etc.). Not all seismic stations record all earthquakes, so there are a variable number of stations that record each earthquake.
Currently, I organize this data in a Pandas DataFrame object, with one line per earthquake. Since there are a variable number of stations for each earthquake, I store the station IDs as a numpy array. Here is a simple example, with earthquakes 0001 and 0002 of magnitude 2.1 and 3.1, respectively. Four seismic stations, a, b, c, and d, have sampling rates of 100, 100, 60, and 60, respectively.
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

events = {
    'event_id': ['0001', '0002'],
    'mag': [2.1, 3.1],
    'station_ids': [np.array(['a', 'c']), np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])],
    'station_sampling_rate': [np.array([100, 60]), np.array([100, 100, 60, 60])]
}
events = pd.DataFrame(events)
print(events)

which results in
  event_id  mag   station_ids station_sampling_rate
0     0001  2.1        [a, c]             [100, 60]
1     0002  3.1  [a, b, c, d]    [100, 100, 60, 60]

Now, when I need station-specific information from this DataFrame, either I need to:

Loop through each line of events and perform some check, and compare to an existing catalog of stations (slow)
Construct events in such a way that it holds increasingly more station-specific information for each station (events gets really big), and still loop through each line of events

Method 1 has worked for me so far, but is slow. Method 2 seems like a waste of resources.
The desired structure of the above example is this:
  station_id  sampling_rate     event_ids         mag
0          a            100  [0001, 0002]  [2.1, 3.1]
1          b            100        [0002]       [3.1]
2          c             60  [0001, 0002]  [2.1, 3.1]
3          d             60        [0002]       [3.1]

Is there an efficient way to structure, store, and transform this data? It seems there has to be something existing already to deal with this type of data.
I tried searching, but I don't know what this data structure is called, or if it has a name.

#2 as you’ve described it is generally accepted as standard especially when you take into account this is how the concept of normalization in traditional relational database systems looks. However your statement “still loop through each line of events” signals that you don’t fully understand the tool you’ve chosen (pandas). Bluntly, there are very few reasons why you’d ever iterate a DataFrame (and if you find you need to do it a lot, it’s likely you’ve chosen the wrong data structure entirely). Use its syntax properly , ie df[df['station_id'] == 'a'] for station a’s rows. (1/2)

Accessing your DataFrame like this (as intended) will provide eons better performance optimizations under the hood than you could reasonably expect from any loop-based solution. Separately, I wouldn’t personally worry about the size of events unless you have a really good reason to do so, as pandas is optimized for processing datasets that are likely larger in scale than yours (although without more information on this from you we can’t affirmatively say whether your concerns are founded or not). (2/2)

Also- don’t forget that bringing your DataFrame to a more normalized state doesn’t have to be painful when you can use the tools that pandas gives you - relevant SO thread (3/2)

BTW I would be inclined to call this "denormalised" - since a normalised representation would most likely consist of multiple tables (one containing stations, another containing events with station_id, even_id, mag columns maybe). You should be able to store this efficiently in parquet as it allows for list or struct (or list of struct) fields.

But I agree with the previous comments, unless you run into performance issues - store and manipulate as normalised. And if you run into performance issues - you can probably fix them by using polars / duckdb or other options and still keep the data normalised.

Great, thank you all. I'm new to pandas and databases, but this normalization concept is exactly what I was looking for but didn't have a word for.

Looping through rows is intrinsically very slow in Pandas and (almost) never needed. For the example given:
events2 = events.explode(['station_ids', 'station_sampling_rate'])

results = events2.groupby(['station_ids', 'station_sampling_rate'], as_index = False)[['mag', 'event_id']].agg(list)

print(results)

gives the DF:
  station_ids station_sampling_rate         mag      event_id
0           a                   100  [2.1, 3.1]  [0001, 0002]
1           b                   100       [3.1]        [0002]
2           c                    60  [2.1, 3.1]  [0001, 0002]
3           d                    60       [3.1]        [0002]


Works perfectly, thank you.
